# Versioning database?

Tags: database-design

I am making a database for a sportsclub, with coaches and players. The players are able to create themselves and coaches are able to create and update players too.

How do I make the edit part, so that only one coach can update a players info at the time.
I'm thinking using versioning. Making a version row in each table and updating it whenever it is edited, to make sure that only one person can edit it at the time.

Any other suggestions on how to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . Your proposal is feasible.

Assume that you load an record  from the database with id = 1 and version = 1 into your application . You then modify it . When issuing  UPDATE SQL to update the changes , you should update and include the checking  for the version column too .

The UPDATE SQL should look like :

```
update ITEM set REMARK="SOME UPDATE REMARK!!" , VERSION= @origianl_vesrion +1 
where ITEM_ID=1 and VERSION=@origianl_vesrion
```

Note : @origianl_vesrion is the value of the version column at the moment when it is loaded into your application)

If another transaction updates and commits the same row before you commit , the update row count for the issued SQL **will be zero** as  the VERSION column is increased by that transaction and will no longer equal to 1 .

So , if the  update row count is zero , you can  display an error message saying something like "Someone changes the same record too , please retry"

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you have 3 choices.

**Locking**

You create a mechanism to "lock" records. This means that no other user can get write access to that record while you've got it open for editing. In practice, this is horrible - as duedl0r says, the failure modes are exorbitant, and for your application, it's probably not worth doing.

**Comparison**

This is the most common model I've come across. When retrieving the record from the database, prior to editing, you find a way of identifying that record - typically by hashing all fields together. Once the user has completed their changes, you retrieve the same record from the database, compare it against the (hash of) your original snapshot, and notify the user if the record has changed in the meantime.

**Ignore it, or design the possibility away**

Given that you're dealing with very small numbers of concurrent users, the risk of this happening may be negligible, so you may choose not to deal with it. Alternatively, you could design the application so that coaches can only modify their own players.

You probably also want to build in some logic to stop coaches creating duplicate players - notoriously tricky. Is "Peter Michael Smith" the same player as "Pete Smith"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'lock' table that contains the Id of the coach and the Id of the player. When editing, check for existance of both Ids in the table and act accordingly. When editing has been completed, you can then remove this entry.